# Run Script in SolarWinds Orion via Python

Tags: python, beginner

I've been using Python for about two months now and I know that there is a lot of improvement to be made.

This script runs a command against a device within our SolarWinds Orion environment. The script works fine, I'd love to know how I could make improvements on the code quality and methods that are used.

I appreciate any help and suggestions that you can offer!

```
from orionsdk import SwisClient
import time
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

sw_server = ####
username  = ####
password  = ####
device_ip = "192.0.0.0"
swis = SwisClient(sw_server, username, password)

# Get the device's NodeID to be able to point the query at the specific device
data = swis.query(f"SELECT NodeID, ReverseDNS, Status, StatusText, DisplayName, LastBoot, AgentIP FROM Cirrus.Nodes WHERE AgentIP = '{device_ip}'")
list = [i['NodeID'] for i in data['results']]
nodeID = (''.join(list))

# Command that we'd like to run against the device
command = 'show version'

# Run command against the device
response = swis.invoke('Cirrus.ConfigArchive', 'ExecuteScript', [nodeID], command)
transfer_id = (''.join(response))
time.sleep(5)

# Check the status of the command:
# Status = 1: Incomplete
# Status = 2: Complete
# I'm guessing that there are more status codes, but I haven't yet discovered them nor their meaning
status = '1'
while status == '1':
    response = swis.query(f"SELECT status, action, DeviceOutput, UserName,TransferID, NodeID, DateTime, ErrorMessage FROM NCM.TransferResults WHERE TransferID = '{transfer_id}'")
    status_code = [i['status'] for i in response['results']]
    status = ",".join(map(str, status_code))
    time.sleep(5)
    if status != '1':
        DeviceOutput = [i['DeviceOutput'] for i in response['results']]
        DeviceOutput = (''.join(DeviceOutput))
        print(DeviceOutput)
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the domain-specific nature of the code there's only a limited amount of review that I can provide, but:

Don't hard-code credentials in source. This is not secure, and is inconvenient for production operations. The credentials should be off-loaded to a permissions-controlled file or wallet system or environment variables that are themselves configured with security in mind.

`(''.join(list))` does not need outer parens.

Do not make a variable called `list` since it shadows a built-in.

Since you only `join` on `list`, don't materialise that comprehension to a list `[]`; instead leave it as a generator like

```
node_id = ''.join(i['NodeID'] for i in data['results'])
```

Further, it seems like you should expect only one result from your query, and you should terminate the script if that isn't the case, so unpack the query:

```
data = swis.query(f"SELECT NodeID, ReverseDNS, Status, StatusText, DisplayName, LastBoot, AgentIP FROM Cirrus.Nodes WHERE AgentIP = '{device_ip}'")
result, = data['results']
node_id = result['NodeID']
```

Another problem is injection vulnerability. If [this source](https://github.com/nlgotz/swisclient/blob/master/swisclient/swisclient.py#L16) corresponds to the client library that you're using, then it has a `params` you need to prefer over string formatting.

You should delete your first `sleep()`. Since your second `sleep` is in a polling loop there's probably no avoiding it.

Rather than putting a placeholder value in `status`, convert to a forever-loop; tuple-unpack single query results; and don't unnecessarily degrade an integer to a string:

```
while True:
    response = swis.query(f"SELECT status, action, DeviceOutput, UserName,TransferID, NodeID, DateTime, ErrorMessage FROM NCM.TransferResults WHERE TransferID = '{transfer_id}'")
    result, = response['results']
    if result['status'] != 1:
        break

device_output = result['DeviceOutput']
print(device_output)
```

That isn't tested, of course, so YMMV.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! This is exactly what I was hoping for. I need to do some research on the `prams` to find out how to properly integrate that, but it seems to be a good move here.
For the `sleep()` line in the loop, I had integrated that so that it wasn't repeatedly checking (since each check is separate call to the end point and I didn't want to overwhelm it). Overall these suggestions are great! Thank you